# On Google Drive is there a way to connect Adobe Reader using "Connect more apps"

Tags: google-drive

I want to open PDF files using Adobe Reader on the Google web drive. There is no problem on the local Google drive, but when on the web, one has to use various apps offered by Google that are intrusive and require some kind of registration or you are stuck with the Google viewer. Does anyone know of a trick or work around to allow one to use Adobe Reader as the default reader when on the network Google drive?

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking into a similar issue (for Word and Excel) and all evidence seems to indicate that when using Google Drive on the Web, you can not use applications installed locally on your machine to open files. The best suggestion is to use the Google Drive app to sync the files to your computer then just open them up there.